# Missing JAR for micrometer-commons:1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001

Tags: java, maven, micrometer

[`io.micrometer:micrometer-core:micrometer-core-1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001.pom`](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001/) defines a dependency on `io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:micrometer-commons-1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001`

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And [`io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:micrometer-commons-1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001.pom`](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001/) does not specify `<packaging>` to be `pom`. Therefore it is using default packaging type of `jar`.

However, there is no `micrometer-commons-1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001.jar` available [here](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001/).

Is there anything wrong in Micromere 1.10.0.M1-redhat-00001?

Answer (score 1):

The repo that you are using is not the official repo of Micrometer.
Check the docs and the readme, Micrometer artifacts can be found here:

- Stable: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:io.micrometer
- Milestone: https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/milestone/io/micrometer
- Snapshot: https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/snapshot/io/micrometer

If you want to use the non-official redhat repo, please contact redhat support.